# What happens if an elf and a giant have a child?

Tags: dnd-5e, races, elf

I wonder what species would come out if an elf (any kind) and a giant would have a child. Which species would it belong to? What would be the appearance of it? Is it even possible in Dungeons & Dragons fifth edition?

I would like to know if the child would have powers from both its parents.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. "My question though, is more of a metaphorical question, so it is directed to any kind of game." - This doesn't really make it any more answerable on RPG.SE, which is a site about role-playing games; different RPGs may handle it entirely differently, even from edition to edition of the same game. This sort of question might be a better question for fit for [Worldbuilding.SE](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This question is still Too Broad when it asks for "how to balance such powers". There are too many theoretical options for that question. After receiving the answer to the first question, if you decide on an implementation, we can answer a question about balance for that specific implementation.

Comment: Overlooking the pragmatic issue of *the lady elf dies in child birth* if elf and giant mate, or, *the lady giant doesn't realize the baby slipped out and it landed on its  head from 11 feet up*  if elf and giant mate - are you trying to create a PC viable race, or an NPC, with this question?  I ask because  PC races are Medium in size like and elf is (and a few small) while giants are Huge (two size categories larger).  Something seems to be missing in the question in re "what problem are we trying to solve here" .. and I also am unsure how a Goliath doesn't already answer the question.

Comment: Have you reviewed the Elemental Evil Players Guide (free at WoTC web site) or Volo's Guide to Monsters?  (Book)

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Let's say that the giant isn't that big, and it also could be a half giant. I'm pretty sure that giants and humans have mated already sometime, because of that I could assume that there could be a child out of an elf and a giant. Why is this question so difficult to understand?

Comment: What kind of elf? What kind of giant? Are you looking for some sort of homebrew rules to create a playable race out of them? Are you looking for canon examples of a half giant/half elf? Right now it's not clear what your actual question is. Are you just curious, or are you trying to turn this into a character?

Comment: @Theik Actually I'm just curious, but I would also like to know if there are some canon examples from the past.

Comment: I'm starting to think that this question is more of a general question and that this question should perhaps be on another site. Please suggest which site I should use for this question. As I'm trying to find out if it is possible in any scenario and game...

Comment: @GogoDev: If you want theory-crafting outside of any rules system, you could ask on worldbuilding stack exchange, but you would still need to alter your question to fit a scope. On worldbuilding, you would need to explain what abilities elves and giants had in your world, plus what your goal was for inventing the hybrid race - e.g. would you want the hybrid to have an established role in elf or giant society etc.

Comment: @NeilSlater Thanks for clearing it up. Perhaps I will.

Comment: We maintain a [a list of forums here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/22566), which may provide ideas on a place to ask a question of this nature.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast thx.

Comment: [This question on the wordlbuilding site](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/161560/what-happens-if-an-elf-and-a-giant-have-a-child)